# missing permissions in list

Tags: node.js, discord.js

for the command to work it needs 3 permissions, but how could I reduce its size and simplify it for it to identify the missing ones and send a list, and not go from one in one?

e.g.

```
list = {
USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS: 'use external emojis',
EMBED_LINKS: 'embed links', 
READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: 'read message history'
}
```

CODE:

```
if (!message.channel.permissionsFor(client.user).has('USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS' && 'EMBED_LINKS'))  {
        return message.channel.send('missing permissions use external emojis and embed links');
    }
  if (!message.channel.permissionsFor(client.user).has('EMBED_LINKS'))  {
        return message.channel.send('missing permission embed links');
    }
  if (!message.channel.permissionsFor(client.user).has('USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS'))  {
        return message.message.channel.send('missing permission use external emojis');
    }

  if (!message.channel.permissionsFor(client.user).has('READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY'))  {
        return message.channel.send('missing permission read message history');
    }
```

Comment: I don’t think has uses && operator, consider changing it to `.has(...) && ....has(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries()` to get an iterable array of `key - value` pairs and use a method like this

```js
const neededPermsObj = {
USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS: 'use external emojis',
EMBED_LINKS: 'embed links', 
READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: 'read message history'
}

const missingPerms = [];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(neededPermsObj)) {
    if (!message.channel.permissionsFor(client.user).has(key.toString())) {
    missingPerms.push(`${key}: ${value}`)
    }
}
if (missingPerms.length != 0) return message.channel.send(missingPerms.join('\n')); // prevent from running cmd
else // execute command code here
```

This would check if bot has the specified permissions from the object provided, and will return an array with all the missing permissions